# How to get TIME in C++, preferably multi platform

Tags: c++

I've been using **GetTickCount()** from Windows but I've read that it has poor performance/resolution, and I'd like to ask what is the best way to get the time.

I tried using the **<ctime>** library but it doesn't go for miliseconds or microseconds, and I need something up to that precision.

Thanks!

Comment: This is likely answered on Stackoverflow.com already, and this question probably belongs there.

Comment: if you are using C++11 you can use std::chrono, otherwise I don't think there is a high precision cross-platform method available.

Comment: As a general bit of advice, "cross-platform" is just a short way of saying "constrainted to the least common denominator."  Especially in games, you're going to have to come to terms with having per-platform `#ifdef`s here and there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using C++11, you can use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

Precision is an implementation detail, e.g it should be implemented as `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << "It took " << std::chrono::nanoseconds(t2 - t1).count() << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that i said _should_ because of the the issue outlined here.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/

Answer (score 1):

If you want cross-platform compatibility, the `clock()` function from `ctime` (see [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/)) is probably your best bet.  It's in milliseconds in Visual Studio (although that's no guarantee that it actually advances in 1-millisecond increments), and is presumably similar in other compilers.

Each platform will have its own way of getting higher-resolution timing.  On Windows there are `timeGetTime()` and `QueryPerformanceCounter()`.  You can read about them online; there are tons of articles about each ([here's one](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/timegettime-versus-gettickcount/)).  If there are other platforms you care about, you'll have to google around or consult their docs for their own high-resolution timing functions.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this, its performance seems better
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time.html